# R fitting polynomial to data - difficulty with data in dataframe

Tags: r, plot, curve

I have the following example to fit a 3rd order polynomial to data:

```
# rm(list = ls(all = TRUE)) # clear workspace
var2 <- c(32,64,96,118,126,144,152.5,158)
var3 <- c(99.5,104.8,108.5,100,86,64,35.3,15)
fit1 <- lm(var3 ~ poly(var2,3,raw=TRUE))
plot(var2, var3 , pch=19, ylim=c(0,150))
xx <- seq(30,160, length = 20)
lines(xx, predict(fit1, data.frame(var2 = xx)), col="blue")
```

This works. However, I am having some trouble adapting this approach to my own data in a dataframe:

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
mydf <- data.frame(var2 = c(32, 64, 96, 118, 126, 144, 152.5, 158), var3 = c(99.5, 104.8, 108.5, 100, 86, 64, 35.3, 15))
fit2 <- lm(mydf$var3 ~ poly(mydf$var2,3,raw=TRUE))
xx <- seq(min(mydf$var2), max(mydf$var2), length = 10)    
plot(mydf$var2, mydf$var3 , pch=19, ylim=c(0,150))
lines(xx, predict(fit2, data.frame(var2 = xx)), col="blue")
```

This produces the error "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ" which I am having trouble sorting out.  I have examined the properties of each part of the second block of code, still can't find the problem. I am sure I am overlooking something very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do things like predict from a model, you should use the `data` argument rather than `$` syntax, e.g.

```
fit2 <- lm(var3 ~ poly(var2,3,raw=TRUE), data=mydf)
lines(xx, predict(fit2, data.frame(var2 = xx)), col="blue")
```

For what it's worth, orthogonal polynomials (i.e omit `raw=TRUE`) are more numerically stable; if you don't need to interpret the coefficients as intercept/linear/quadratic/cubic trends *at zero*, you'll be better off that way in the long run.

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem completely. Except I don't understand why the other way didn't work - that is, what is the difference between the two examples.And thanks for the tip about raw=TRUE

Comment: @ marcel: I also wanted to ask the same to @BenBolker. Why mydf$var3 etc does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing length to 8 in xx:

```
mydf <- data.frame(var2 = c(32, 64, 96, 118, 126, 144, 152.5, 158), var3 = c(99.5, 104.8, 108.5, 100, 86, 64, 35.3, 15))
fit2 <- lm(mydf$var3 ~ poly(mydf$var2,3,raw=TRUE))
xx <- seq(min(mydf$var2), max(mydf$var2), length = 8)    
plot(mydf$var2, mydf$var3 , pch=19, ylim=c(0,150))
lines(xx, predict(fit2, data.frame(var2 = xx)), col="blue")
```

[image]

It works though it does not fit very well.

Comment: your answer works, sort of, but will be disappointing if the OP wants to use the results to interpolate ...

Comment: Yes. Your answer is perfect. I think I should delete my answer.

Comment: For reasons that I don't understand, with this solution, although the error goes away, the fit is very poor, in contrast with the original example. Also, in the original example it works perfectly fine to set length = a large number (e.g. 100) ....